# Duplicate duplicates the active tab and not the selected one

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

The option *"Duplicate"* in the context menu of a tab creates a duplicate of the active tab and not of the tab where the context menu is opened and the command is selected.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix is rolling out with next build (build rev `2015.10.28.3794` on MSE/MSO, `2015.10.28.2913` on sites).